# DCOM Running Processes Dump Location

Tags: dcom

In DCOM user security (dcomcnfg), under

- Console Root

  - Component Serveices

    - My Computer

      - Running Processes

if I right-click a running process and select Dump from the menu, I get the following dialog box:

```
The dump of the selected process succeeded.
The image was dumped to the default dump directory.
```

Where is the default dump directory? How can I find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under `%SystemRoot%\system32\com\dmp`.

<sup><sup>[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145600.aspx)</sup></sup>

Comment: Cheers Karan! What tools can be used top view the (looks-like-binary-format) dmp?